# Unity: fixed joystick не до конца двигается в левую сторону

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я скачал и поставил виртуальный джойстик - https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/joystick-pack-107631
Почему-то этот джойстик влево идет меньше, чем вправо.
Видео - https://youtu.be/mPb47QUhReg
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

В коде проблема была, в FixedJoystick:

```
в методе: void Start() 
(cam, background.position); 
Нужно сменить background на handle: 
(cam, handle.position);
```